# Is it possible to get a working tree in a bare git repo?

Tags: git

I'm currently using gitolite, and in my post-receive hook I'm pushing to a (local) mirror if any incoming commits are on master.

Thing is, *that* mirror only exists because I want to automate deployment & testing on pushes to master: I can't get at the index files in the `work.git`, so I push to a non-bare `work` repo to get a working tree, and run a completely separate post-receive hook.

I have two problems with this approach:

1. It feels dumb
2. If tests fail I get emails notifying me, instead of a rejected commit. (Not actually that big of a problem in terms of frequency, I just don't like it.)

What's the standard way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not dumb. Bare repositories are called bare for a reason. (I assume this is what you mean by "raw".)

To answer your real question, I think you need to take a step back and ask what you're actually trying to do. Do you want to reject a *commit*? Commits are local, nothing to do with pushing, so you'd have to run the automated tests yourself, whether in a pre-commit hook or manually. Do you want to reject a push? **post**-receive (or post-update) is too late for that but if you really wanted to, you could run the tests in a **pre**-receive (or update) hook. I suspect this is a bad idea though: tests take time, and I'm not sure you actually want to wait while your push hangs until the tests finish. (The deal about having separate repositories is not really relevant - the hook runs some commands, and whether or not they involve another repository, they have to finish before the hook exits.)

But maybe a more sustainable workflow would be: push to a pre-master branch, let the automated tests go, and when they *complete*, automatically push to the master branch. If the tests fail, the master branch won't be updated, and you can get your email and go check it out.

Comment: This all makes sense, especially the part about not wanting to wait for the tests to finish on push. Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196626/25616) I think I might be able to do something with merging into master on the dev side using pre-update hooks, too.