# How do I set up git to warn me if I am about to push to master in a specific repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to know if there is a way to get a warning if I try to push directly to my remote master.

Comment: Where and how do you want to get that warning?

Comment: I suppose on the command line… I am basically hoping that there is a setting somewhere that I set on either my repo or git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git pre-push hooks is what you are looking for

You could use a client side hook or a server side hook depending on your needs.

All about hooks: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: It seems that it is what I am looking for but is not official yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960839/why-doesnt-git-have-a-pre-push-hook