# How can I check for whitespace/tab errors in my git commit?

Tags: git

Is there any way I can check for whitespace/tab (i.e. don't use tab, use spaces instead, and do have end of line space) in my git commits?

I have ~ 10 commits, I want to double check them before I push.

What Git mechanism should apply for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to "double check" is through a **[pre-commit hook to detect whitespace errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592014/6309)**.
(You will find [hook examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516525/6309) there)

Trying to do that just before a push is a bit late, even though [git1.8.2 has now a pre-push hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672883/6309).

You can still:

- put a pre-commit hook in place
- do a `rebase -i HEAD~10` (replaying all your 10 commits), which will trigger that pre-commit hook.