# Can a server determine the git version of the user client/agent

Tags: githooks

Can I use git hook to determine the version of the client/agent pushing?

I want to deny a push and send a message when the user/client is too old (or too new).

Answer (score 1):

Not on the server side, as that information (git version) isn't part of what is being pushed.

You could ask the client to have a [`pre-push` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672883/6309) with your test in it, but there is no guarantee that this hook would be deployed (or bypassed by the user).