# How to automate mvn verify just after every git commit on local machine?

Tags: bash, git, maven, commit, verify

Everytime i commit changes using git bash, i want mvn verify to get executed before a git push. I always forget that and then pipeline gets failed. Any suggestions/plugins on IntelliJ is also welcomed.

Comment: You can create a continuous integration (CI) workflow in GitHub Actions to build and test your Java project with Maven.

Comment: @Parth Is this possible on local machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified anything about github, so I assume plain git here.

With this in mind there are a couple of ways you can try:

1. Instead of using `git push` make yourself accustomed to use a script that you'll write (put it in an alias or something). Like `alias gp = <run maven> <check result> <if ok> -> push, otherwise <fail>`
2. Another way is using a pre-push git hook (available since 1.8.2) With this approach, you'll create a scipt in your git repository and it will execute when you do `git push` right before it actually sends the data to the server. The hook implementation will basically do the same thing as I've described in item 1.

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196148/git-pre-push-hooks) closely related SO thread.