# Why does jsonlines package get resolved to registry.npm.taobao.org?

Tags: npm, jsonlines

When I install the npm package [jsonlines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlines), it gets resolved to a mirrored registry `registry.npm.taobao.org` rather than `registry.npmjs.org`. It only does this for `jsonlines`. What causes this?

Here's the diff on my package-lock.json. The original "resolved" value was created when another developer installed the package:

```json
     "jsonlines": {
       "version": "0.1.1",
-      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonlines/-/jsonlines-0.1.1.tgz",
+      "resolved": "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/jsonlines/download/jsonlines-0.1.1.tgz",
       "integrity": "sha1-T80kbcXQ44aRkHxEqwAveC0dlMw="
     },
```

I confirmed my configured registry is npmjs.org:

```
$ npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1431?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developer's npm registry was likely set to `registry.npm.taobao.org` when they ran `npm install jsonlines`. Some users have npm configured to use the taobao registry for geographic proximity.

Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-running `npm install` fixes it.

---

**Tip**: Use [lockfile-lint](https://github.com/lirantal/lockfile-lint/tree/master/packages/lockfile-lint) to prevent it from happening again.

1. `npm install --save-dev lockfile-lint`
2. Run `lockfile-lint` to your lint script, ideally in a [pre-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196148/git-pre-push-hooks) git hook.
3. Add this config to your `package.json`:

```json
  "lockfile-lint": {
    "allowed-schemes": [
      "https:"
    ],
    "allowed-hosts": [
      "npm"
    ],
    "empty-hostname": false,
    "type": "npm ",
    "path": "package-lock.json"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Found your comment in this [github issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1431#issuecomment-725583783) as well ^_^ Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-running `npm install` does fix it for me!