# Interrupt `git push` with prompt

Tags: git

I keep on pushing w/o updating snapshots for Jest snapshot tests in a pipeline. This is probably annoying my co-workers during a merge request process (because the reviewers get an email every push to MR).

What I would like to do is interrupt the push with a simple prompt to self like so:

```
git push
Did you remember to update snapshots? [y/n]
```

And, then either continue with the push or cancel if `no`.

I know I could make an alias with some other command name altogether, but I don't want to stop using `git push`. I just want to interrupt it. Ideas?

Comment: I think you could do this with a git pre-push hook

Comment: Use a pre-push hook, or write your own `git` front end (alias in bash for instance) that checks to see if the command will be `git push`. (Use `command git` in the alias to run the binary instead of the alias.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git pre-push hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196148/git-pre-push-hooks)

Comment: Not yet, but good direction. My Mac has no `core.hooksPath` set, local or global. Thanks to the hints from comments I did find my `pre-commit-template`, which I did use to successfully prompt myself, but only when running script at command line.
I've attempted to add `core.hooksPath` to my git configuration to no avail. Will post when I have this working.